# Why is a whitespace character only represented by 6 bits in ASCII?

Tags: python, encryption, ascii

I have written a code in python to represent strings using their ASCII counterparts. I have noticed that every character is replaced by 7 bits (as I expected). The problem is that every time I include a space in the string I am converting it is only represented by 6 bits instead of 7. This is a bit of a problem for a Vernam Cipher program I am writing where my ASCII code is always a few bits smaller than my key due to spaces. Here is the code and output below:

```
string = 'Hello t'
ASCII = ""
for c in string:
    ASCII += bin(ord(c)) 
ASCII = ASCII.replace('0b', ' ')

print(ASCII)
```

Output: 1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110100

As can be seen in the output the 6th sequence of bits which represents the space character has only 6 bits and not 7 like the rest of the characters.

Comment: It's not six bits, it's `00100000`, which becomes `100000` when the leading zeros are removed.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I convert a space to as ASCII binary code I get this: 0b100000 When I convert a normal letter, for example 'e' I get this: 0b1100101. In the case of 'e' there are seven bits after the '0b' but in the case of the space there are only six. Is this because of the '0b'? I thought that was only to represent that the following characters are treated as binary? I'm not sure if my response makes sense but I just don't get why all the normal letters have seven bits after the '0b' and space has six.

Comment: Well, a similar argument can be made for `'e'` (or any character), the code for `'e'` is `01100101`, but `bin` removes the leading zero(s), so you see only `1100101`. This is similar to the decimal system for instance, where `42 = 042 = 0042 = 00042 = ...etc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `bin(ord(c))`, which will automatically strip leading bits, use string formatting to ensure a minimum width:

```
f'{ord(c):07b}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within your "conversion" - the value for whitespace happens to only need 6 bits, and the `bin` built-in simply don't do left padding with zeros. That is why you are getting 7 bits for other chars - but it would really be more confortable if you would use 8 bits for everything.

One way to go is, instead of using the `bin` call, use string formatting operators: these can, besides the base conversion, pad the missing bits with 0s:

```
string = 'Hello t'
# agregating values in a list so that you can easily separate the binary strings with a " "
# by using ".join"
bin_strings = []
for code in string.encode("ASCII"): # you really should do this from bytes -
     #which are encoded text. Moreover, iterating a bytes
     # object yield 0-255 ints, no need to call "ord"
     bin_strings.append(f"{code:08b}")  # format the number in `code` in base 2 (b), with 8 digits, padding with 0s 
ASCII = ' '.join(bin_strings)
```

Or, as a oneliner:

```
ASCII = " ".join(f"{code:08b}" for code in "Hello World".encode("ASCII"))
```

Comment: OP seems to want 07b, no?

Comment: That is his call. There is a reason why computers use 8 bit bytes from the 70's on, and I mention that. Other than that, just replace "8" with  "7" where appropriate.

Comment: (btw: not needing "ord" with bytes is a nice "bonus" here - trying to convert a text "str" object to binary using only "ord" is incorrect, that is why I encoded to bytes first. One example of things going wrong is with characters that with codepoints that don't fit in 8 bit).

Comment: But ascii does.